# Convert to text a pdf which is generated from oracle reports (Oracle10gR2 AS Reports Services)

Tags: oracle, pdf, reporting-services, pdftotext

Need to convert to text file a pdf report. PDF is generated from Oracle Reports, Oracle10gR2 AS Reports Services.

Any tool, or guideline is kindly appreciated.

Note :

I have tested already the following, but for PDF generated from Oracle10gR2 AS Reports Services, the text file produced is useless.

```
www.colorpilot.com/pdf2text.html
blog.alivate.com.au/poppler-windows/
www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html
www.coolutils.com/CommandLine/TotalPDFConverter
www.opoosoft.com/pdf-text.html
```

Comment: I don't think the `reporting-services` tag applies here, as this is not related to `SSRS`

Comment: Can't you change the format the report is generated? Oracle Reports allows other formats that might be easier to extract text from

Comment: Can you share a sample PDF those extractors failed to extract text from? This way one can check before mentioning a product...

Comment: I met the same problem